# Search string with re module in html page

Tags: python, regex, full-text-search, web-scraping

I have html page with javascript
There is some js code in html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewAllLimiter = 0;
</script>
```

how can I find **viewAllLimiter** and take its value with re.search?

I have tried:

```
#hh2 - opened page with urllib2
re.search('var viewAllLimite = "(\w)"', hh2)
```

I need output like:

```
var viewAllLimiter = 0;
```

or anything else that I know i see value of viewAllLimiter parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `re.findall` method and groups.  This will return a list with your groups as members.  Also, if you want to match numbers > 9 with your regex you'll need a '+' after \w.  Also, if you're sure that the value will always be a number it's better to use \d+.

```
re.findall( r'(viewAllLimiter =) (\w+)', txt )
```

this will return

```
[('viewAllLimiter =', '0')]
```

for your example but also will return

```
[('viewAllLimiter =', '9924')]
```

if the value is a larger number.  Note the tuple inside the list.  This is because you get one tuple for each pattern match and each item in the tuple is one of your groups.  One last thing to keep in mind when using regex, you will save yourself a lot of headaches by using [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#raw-string-notation) (the `r` in front of the leading quote).

To match a more general class of variables you can use the following regex,

```
re.findall( r"""\s*(CATEGORY_ID)\s*=\s*((?:'|")?\w+(?:'|")?)""", txt )
```

which will capture anything in quotes (or not) as long as you put the variable name you're searching for in the beginning of the regex.  Note that this returns the quotes along with the value, for example `[('SKU', '"GRP05133"')]`.  If you want just the value you can make the second group tight around the `\w+` part.

```
re.findall( r"""\s*(CATEGORY_ID)\s*=\s*(?:'|")?(\w+)(?:'|")?""", txt )
```

If we break this regex down it says,

```
"""
\s*       # zero or more white spaces
(xxx)     # the variable you're looking for
\s*       # zero or more white spaces
=         # an equal sign
\s*       # zero or more white space
(?:'|")?  # zero or one ' or " but non-capturing (i.e. don't store in group output)
(\w+)     # the value of the variable
(?:'|")?  # zero or one single quote OR zero or one double quote
"""
```

Comment: but it doesnt work for other js variables if Im using your pattern

Comment: can you expand your question to show this or ask a new one?

Comment: here is something to get you started. to match quotes w/o ending the string I'm using for the regex, I use triple quotes to contain my regex   `r"""\s*=\s*(['"]?\w+['"]?)"""`   this says match zero or more white spaces then '=' then zero or more white spaces followed by something that may be in single or double quotes

Answer (score 0):

You can use named groups:

```
m=re.search(r"var viewAllLimiter =(?P<myFancyName>\w);", s)
```

and then, to access the value (in your case 0), you do

```
m.groupdict()["myFancyName"]
```

to have access to the value of `viewAllLimiter` and `groupdict()` returns a dictionary with all named groups in the reg-exp.

Comment: if you want to find ALL occurences of it, you have to use `findall` instead of `search`